# Should I Include Dell OS Recovery Drives in Windows 10 System Restore (System Protection)?

Tags: windows, dell-inspiron, system-restore

Should Windows System Protection (Restore Points) be enabled for the "Image" and "DELLSUPPORT" drives that appear under "Available Drives"?

I have also created "Program Files" and "ProgramData" folders on my secondary hard drive to install some larger programs on, should I have System Restore enabled for the secondary hard drive?

I have also moved the locations of my Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Music and Videos folders to my secondary hard drive, using the "Location" tab in the Properties windows of those folders.

I've read that Windows System Restore can have problems restoring a Restore Point, if the secondary drive is enabled for Restore Points.

[image: My Restore Point Drives]

Comment: Side note: My experience is that Restore Points, however implemented, occasionally do *not* repair an issue, particularly where the Registry is involved. They give a false sense of security,. Be sure you also make full drive images for all drives periodically.

Comment: In 20 years my success rate with restoring a Point has been probably 3%. I still make them but I make drive images regularly with a 3rd party tool. I'm wondering if it's because I install larger programs on my second larger HD and maybe that is causing issues, whether with how the reg keys are written, or some access issue, etc.